# Why Cant I Pass This JSON Object to Another Activity

Tags: java, android, json

I am fetching news Items from Json using Volley. In the MainActivity I have successfully fetched and parsed the json, so I have no problem with that.
Now each news item contains a title and an excerpt of the news. What I wanted was that each time the news excerpt is clicked, it will start another activity called **NewsDetails**,
 during the starting, the "ID" (a json object) of the news excerpt clicked, will be sent to **NewsDetails**.

In **NewsDetails** I will concatenate the "ID" and the url of the website; this will also return a json array. Then I'll parse the json and display it; hopefully this won't give me a problem.

Where I am experiencing difficulties is trying to send the "ID" and starting the "NewsDetails".

So far this is what I have been doing:

**All MainActivity class**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //Creating a list of newss
    private List<NewsItems> mNewsItemsList;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device rotated and onCreate called");

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.news_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        //Initializing the newslist
        mNewsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(mNewsItemsList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        //Caling method to get data
         getData();

    }


    //This method will get data from the web api

    private void getData(){


        Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
        //Showing progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.load_news));
        mProgressDialog.show();


        //Creating a json request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ConfigNews.GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();
                        }
                        /*progressDialog.dismiss();*/


                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        Log.d(TAG, "Parsing array");

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            NewsItems newsItem = new NewsItems();
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                newsItem.setNews_title(jsonObject.getString(ConfigNews.TAG_NEWS_TITLE));
                newsItem.setNews_excerpt(jsonObject.getString(ConfigNews.TAG_NEWS_EXCERPT));
                newsItem.setNewsId(jsonObject.getInt(ConfigNews.TAG_NEWS_ID));

            } catch (JSONException w) {
                w.printStackTrace();
            }
            mNewsItemsList.add(newsItem);

        }

        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
        if (mProgressDialog != null){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d(TAG, "mProgress dialog dismissed");

        }
    }

}
```

No problem from the code above.

**The Whole NewsItems class**

```
public class NewsItems {
      private String news_title;
      private String news_excerpt;
      private String news_id;

      public String getNews_title() {
          return news_title;
      }

      public void setNews_title(String news_title) {
          this.news_title = news_title;
      }

      public String getNews_excerpt() {
          return news_excerpt;
      }

      public void setNews_excerpt(String news_excerpt) {
          this.news_excerpt = news_excerpt;
      }

      public String getNews_id() {
          return news_id;
      }

      public void setNews_id(String news_id) {
          this.news_id = news_id;
      }

  }
```

Still no problems from above code.

**All of NewsAdapter**

```
   public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context mContext;

    //List of newss
    private List<NewsItems> mNewsItems;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;

    private int lastPosition = -1;

   public NewsAdapter(List<NewsItems> newsItems, Context context) {
       super();

       //Getting all newss
       this.mNewsItems = newsItems;
       this.mContext = context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionItem(position))
            return VIEW_ITEM;
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }

    private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
       return position != getItemCount()-1;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.news_summ, parent, false);
            return new TextViewHolder(v);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerfooter, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (holder instanceof TextViewHolder) {
            NewsItems newsList = mNewsItems.get(position);
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsTitle.setText(newsList.getNews_title());
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsExcerpt.setText(newsList.getNews_excerpt());
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsId.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.getNewsId()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).loadButton.setText(R.string.reload);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //Return the number of items in the data set
        return mNewsItems.size();
    }




    public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView newsTitle,newsExcerpt, newsId;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public NewsItems dNewsItems;

        public TextViewHolder (final View newsView) {
            super(newsView);
            newsTitle = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            newsExcerpt = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_excerpt);
            newsId = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_id);

            newsExcerpt.setOnClickListener(this);


        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (v.getId() == newsExcerpt.getId()) {
               if (v.getId() == newsExcerpt.getId()) {
               Intent i = NewsDetails.newIntent(getActivity(), dNewsItems.getNews_id());
               startActivity(i);
               }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener{
        Button loadButton;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
            super(footerView);
            loadButton = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.reload_button);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);

            loadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            } else if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                loadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == loadButton.getId()) {
                //
            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is the part that's giving me problems.

Specifically lines

```
Intent i = NewsDetails.newIntent(getActivity(), dNewsItems.getNews_id());
                   startActivity(i);
```

When I hover I hove `newIntent` it says *"Cannot resolve method 'newIntent(?, java.lang.String)'"*.
Then I hover `getActivity()` it says *"Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'"*.
For `startActivity(i);` it's *"Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.Intent)'"*

So now, my question is what am I doing wrong and how should I correct it?

**NewsAdapter After Implementing Rohit Arya's answer**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context mContext;

    //List of newss
    private List<NewsItems> mNewsItems;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 1;

    private int lastPosition = -1;

   public NewsAdapter(List<NewsItems> newsItems, Context context) {
       super();

       //Getting all newss
       this.mNewsItems = newsItems;
       this.mContext = context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionItem(position))
            return VIEW_ITEM;
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }

    private boolean isPositionItem(int position) {
       return position != getItemCount()-1;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.news_summ, parent, false);
            return new TextViewHolder(v, mContext);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_PROG){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerfooter, parent, false);
            return new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (holder instanceof TextViewHolder) {
            NewsItems newsList = mNewsItems.get(position);
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsTitle.setText(newsList.getNews_title());
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsExcerpt.setText(newsList.getNews_excerpt());
            ((TextViewHolder) holder).newsId.setText(String.valueOf(newsList.getNewsId()));

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).loadButton.setText(R.string.reload);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //Return the number of items in the data set
        return mNewsItems.size();
    }




    public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView newsTitle,newsExcerpt, newsId;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public NewsItems dNewsItems;
        private Context context;

        public TextViewHolder (final View newsView, final Context context) {
            super(newsView);
            newsTitle = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            newsExcerpt = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_excerpt);
            newsId = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_id);

            newsExcerpt.setOnClickListener(this);


        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (v.getId() == newsExcerpt.getId()) {
               int newsid = 4536;
               Intent myItent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
               myItent.putExtra("key", newsid);
               context.startActivity(myItent);
               }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener{
        Button loadButton;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
            super(footerView);
            loadButton = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.reload_button);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);

            loadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            } else if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                loadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == loadButton.getId()) {
                //
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**Stacktrace from implementing Rohit Arya's answer**

```
04-12 20:15:25.424 8772-8772/com.newsus.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.newsus.app, PID: 8772
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
                                                                       at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4336)
                                                                       at com.newsus.app.NewsAdapter$TextViewHolder.onClick(NewsAdapter.java:181)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5076)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20279)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

From the stacktrace, line 81, coressponds to line `Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);` of his answer.

Comment: @ cricket_007, it's `onClick`. It's a mistake and I have corrected that.

Comment: Hi did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556147/why-cant-i-pass-this-json-object-to-another-activity/36556283#36556283) work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I should have commented on it before now. I can't say if it worked or not, because the app is crashing for some other reason . I'll fix the crashing and check your answer then.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I have indicated what you have been missing in your solution. I are not setting `this.context = context;` in `TextViewHolder`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `TextViewHolder`'s constructor to receive `context` like this:

```
public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
      public TextView newsTitle, newsExcerpt;
      public ImageButton imageButton;
      public NewsItems dNewsItems;
      private Context context;

      public TextViewHolder (final View newsView, final Context context) {
          super(newsView);
          this.context = context;   // EDIT 1: You are missing this
          newsTitle = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
          newsExcerpt = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_excerpt);
          newsExcerpt.setOnClickListener(this);
      }
```

Now use this context to launch activity like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I tried it but got an NPE. I have updated the question with the full **NewsAdapter class** and stacktrace.

Comment: Where are you creating instance of `NewsAdapter`, can you post that too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the **Mainactivity**

Comment: The error seems to be in `PostAdapter` **not** in `NewsAdapter`. Here look at this: `at com.newsus.app.PostAdapter$TextViewHolder.onClick(PostAdapter.java:181)`

Comment: @Ozuf, can you update `NewsAdapter` code so that I can see how are you using it?

Comment: Yes, it's in NewsAdapter. Before I paste my code here, I changed the names of classes and variables. I forgot to change the name of PostAdapter to NewsAdapter. Hope you understand.

Comment: I followed your instructions explicitly, and I changed lines `Intent i = NewsDetails.newIntent(getActivity(), dNewsItems.getNews_id()); startActivity(i)` in my code to `int newsid = 4484; Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NewsDetails.class); myIntent.putExtra("key", newsid);  context.startActivity(myIntent);` I used the `int newsid` to first test if it'll work before calling the method the get the newsid of the clicked item.

Comment: I think context is null here.. so you have not correctly used it. That's why asked you to post the code.

Comment: @Ozuf, you are not initializing `context` here:

`private Context context;

        public TextViewHolder (final View newsView, final Context context) {
            super(newsView);
   
            this.context = context; //YOU ARE MISSING THIS

            newsTitle = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            newsExcerpt = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_excerpt);
            newsId = (TextView) newsView.findViewById(R.id.news_id);

            newsExcerpt.setOnClickListener(this);


        }`

Comment: I have updated the question with NewsAdapter after implemeting your answer . But note that in line `private Context context;` when I hover `context` , Android Studio is saying that *private field 'context' is never assigned*

    And in line  `public TextViewHolder (final View postView, final Context context)` ; when I hover `context` Android Studio is saying that *parameter 'context' is never used.

Comment: @Ozuf, check my updated answer.  I have edited to indicate what have you been missing.

Comment: thanks it works if I pass it the int value,  but when  I try to pass it the id of the clicked post,  it still crashes.

Comment: @Ozuf, that can be discussed in other post. :) Anyway, can you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting my answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I should have done that before complaining. I have accepted and upvoted.

Comment: No issues at all. Happy to help :)

Comment: ok, I have asked the question, please see if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585476/how-to-send-object-value-from-recyclerview-item-to-another-activity

Answer (score 0):

ViewHolder does not have a method `getActivity()` if you need context in a viewholder you have to pass it in your constructor.

same thing with `startActivity()` you need context for that too